# Set Width in a dynamic segmentedButton in sencha touch app

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I am working in a Sencha touch app, and I have a segmentedButton with this feature, from the backend hiding or showing different items, it is a dynamic segmentedButton, for this purpose I need to adjust when for example I have only one option to the size of the segmentedButton would be if the user had all options..and of course centered in the screen..

How to do it?

At the moment my code is:

```
      {
        xtype : 'segmentedbutton',
        itemId: 'surveyEditorSegmentedButton',
        cls   : 'surveyEditorSegmentedButton',
        items : [
          {
            itemId  : 'presenceData',
            iconMask: true
            //pressed : true
          },
          {
            itemId  : 'auxiliaryFields',
            iconMask: true
          },
          {
            itemId  : 'profiles',
            iconMask: true
          },
          {
            itemId  : 'photos',
            iconMask: true
          }
        ]
      }
```

I have seen this link : https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?251841-How-to-stretch-items-inside-a-Segmented-Button-to-100

But it is not exactly the same, my segmentedbutton has a width and in this case is all the screen..

Answer (score 0):

Remove any width attribute from css class and let the width be calculated on the `flex` value.

```
 {
     xtype: 'segmentedbutton',
     itemId: 'surveyEditorSegmentedButton',
     cls: 'surveyEditorSegmentedButton',
     flex     : 1,
     defaults : {
         flex : 1
     },
     items: [{
         itemId: 'presenceData',
         iconMask: true
         //pressed : true
     }, {
         itemId: 'auxiliaryFields',
         iconMask: true
     }, {
         itemId: 'profiles',
         iconMask: true
     }, {
         itemId: 'photos',
         iconMask: true
     }]
 }
```

Comment: I don't have widths in the css, if I let to get the width with the Flex, segmentedButton has the width of the screen but this is not correct, do you know what I mean?

Comment: What do you want then? Do you want fixed width?

Comment: yes, depending if I have one, two, three or four options, always should be centered with the total width but with flexibility, Imagine if the total has 350px, if i have only one option this option should be 350px, if I have two, than 175px for each one...

Comment: That is what flex will do. It will equally distribute available width in all visible buttons.

Comment: adding flex for each item?

Comment: **defaults** config will add it to all items.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98215/discussion-between-inane-and-vvk).